# MX record and Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, dns, gmail, mx-record

I'm having an issue with setting up my Google Apps account.
I believe that my S3 bucket is causing the problem.
I configure the MX records like Google asked me to and today mij DNS providers acknowledged that the records where propagated.

Now when I try to continue the setup of my Google Apps account it's stuck and doesn't provide any info. I have hosted a a static website on a Amazon S3 Bucket.

Trying to see if the MX records are available I used this tool [MX Toolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/)
to see if my MX records where available but they weren't. Anybody with the same problem or some professional advice?

BTW: the domain name is xntriek.be

Answer (score 4):

What I suspect you will have to do is as follows:

1.) change the settings at your DNS registrar to use a different name server.  For my registrar, namecheap, I go to manage -> transfer Name Server to 3rd party (or some variant) -> (leave this screen up - there should be a set of 5+ blank records)

2.) Set up Amazon Route 53.
3.) "Create Hosted Zone" for your domain name in the Route 53 console
4.) This hosted zone should be associated with a "Delegation Set" (right side of R53 console) - 4 records which you will paste into the screen you found in (1) above.
5.) Save that, and configure Route 53 as you would have configured records with your DNS provider.  (CNAME aliasing and mx forwarding)

The reason this must be done in R53 and not at the Registrar is that **setting the cname record alias to, say, www.yourdomain.com.aws.us-east.amazon blah blah blah tells mx traffic to go to amazon for instructions about what to do**.  Of course, there are no further instructions for that traffic if you have not set up Route 53.

I hope this helps!